# How can I run a second window manager?

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, awesome

Specifically, I'd like to run [awesome-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/awesome-git/) at the same time as [awesome](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/awesome/). I've tried running the former from a shell in the latter:

```
$ awesome-git/pkg/awesome-git/usr/bin/awesome
[…] E: awesome: main:653: another window manager is already running (can't select SubstructureRedirect)
```

I get the same result if I [add `--replace`](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1112104&p=6988372#post6988372).

After changing to a different VT:

```
$ awesome-git/pkg/awesome-git/usr/bin/awesome
[…] E: awesome: main:592: cannot open display (error 5)
```

If I try to specify a display I get the following:

```
$ DISPLAY=:1 awesome-git/pkg/awesome-git/usr/bin/awesome
[…] E: awesome: main:592: cannot open display (error 1)
```

I tried to [`rm ~/.Xauthority`](https://superuser.com/a/541996/2259), but that didn't help.

Answer (score 5):

Because of the way X window managers work, you can only run one at a time in an X server. (Oddly enough I can't find an obvious resource to back this up...)

It won't give quite the same effect, but you can easily run a second window manager inside a nested X server such as [Xephyr](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr/):

```
Xephyr :30 -screen 1024x768 &
DISPLAY=:30 xterm &
DISPLAY=:30 awesome-git &
```

This will give you a tiled `awesome-git` running inside a nested 1024×768 screen in your (presumably `awesome`-managed) current X session.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `vncserver` and `vncviewer`:**

- start a VNC server in the backgrounded process by running the `vncserver` [1] command
- start a VNC viewer in your current window manager by running the `vncviewer` [1] command and connect to the VNC server you just started

[1]  On CentOS-7 `vncserver` is provided by the `tigervnc-server` RPM package (if your distro is different then you will have to query your package manager to see what provides the `vncserver`.

[2] On CentOS-7 `vncviewer` is provided by the `tigervnc` RPM package (so again if your distro is diffferent you will have to query your package manager to see what provides `vncviewer`).

---

UPDATE: I just noticed the question is tagged for Arch Linux. So I checked to see if Arch has `vncserver` and it looks like it does have it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC .